# What did Nerevar promise Dagoth Ur?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls

In *Morrowind*, Dagoth Ur repeatedly mentions a promise that Nerevar made to him when they were both mortal.  I've read multiple lore wiki articles and in-game books about Dagoth Ur, Nerevar, the Nerevarine, etc. but I can't tell what this promise is.  The only promise I see is Dagoth Ur promising Nerevar to never use the Tools of Kagrenac or the Heart of Lorkhan.

Comment: Well, Dagoth wanted to destroy the Tools, and promised to guard them until that time. However, Nerevar was persuaded NOT to destroy them by his wife. Perhaps Dagoth was referring to the "promise" of destroying the Tools? Or maybe Nerevar just took too long to return? It's hard to tell since Dagoth is quite insane by the time we meet him in Morrowind.

Comment: I'm pretty familiar with the *Morrowind* lore and I also can't think of anything that Nerevar promised Dagoth, but I don't have *Morrowind* installed anymore. Can you provide some quotes from Dagoth Ur referring to these promises, maybe I can figure it out.

Comment: @Michael Edenfield: Unfortunately I deleted some saves because I was running out of save slots so I can't go back and screenshot it, but I'm planning another playthrough and will try to post some up.

Answer (score 5):

I've found only one reference of a promise that Neverar made to Dagoth-Ur. It is on the www.uesp.net wiki, in the story about [Nerevar at Red Mountain](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Nerevar_at_Red_Mountain):

> "Stay here, loyal Dagoth-Ur, until I return."

Here Neverar promises to return to the Red Mountain as soon as it is decided what to do with the Tools of Kagrenac.

Comment: Good answer, that was about the only thing I could come up with as well. So I'm guessing Nerevar took too long to return, and eventually Dagoth used the Tools & went nuts... although not necessarily in that order.